# getting space at the bottom of page

Tags: html, removing-whitespace

I am getting unwanted white space of about 150px at the bottom of my page. I have tried every possible way to remove that but Iam not able to as I am not getting where is this white space is coming from.
[image showing inspect & error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcWeo.png)

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, I found the error in php section I have added. Margin bottom of 150px that's what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the error in php section I have added. Margin bottom of 150px that's what was causing the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).